Check OLT ZTE C300 Using SNMP & PHP
So i want to develop web apps for monitoring my OLT ZTE C30O Using SNMP and PHP
i already success get a list my ONU
here's my code and output
<?php
$ip = 'my-ip';
$community = 'my-community';

$session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, $ip, $community);

$oid = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3'; 

$result = $session->walk($oid);

if ($result === false) {
    echo "Failed to get value from OID $oid";
} else {
    print_r($result);
}

$session->close();
?>

//output
Array ( [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268566784.1] => STRING: "ONU-1:1" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268566784.2] => STRING: "ONU-1:2" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268566784.3] => STRING: "ONU-1:3" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268567040.2] => STRING: "ONU-2:2" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268567296.1] => STRING: "ONU-3:1" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268567296.2] => STRING: "ONU-3:2" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268567296.3] => STRING: "ONU-3:3" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268567552.1] => STRING: "ONU-4:1" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268567808.1] => STRING: "ONU-5:1" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268701696.1] => STRING: "ONU-16:1" [iso.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.1.1.3.268701696.2] => STRING: "ONU-16:2")

the next step is i want to get my info at my ONU is working or not, i saw a video on youtube

youtube video : https://youtu.be/uV0ew16SuDo
github source code: https://github.com/didikw/zte_c320_monitoring/blob/main/onustate.php

he can get the status ONU with this code
<?php
$status = snmpwalk("OLT-IP", "community", "ZXGPON-SERVICE-MIB::zxGponOntPhaseState"); 
?>
//output
INTEGER: Working (3)

When i do it by myself with this code, it return error
<?php
$ip = 'my-ip';
$community = 'my-community';

// Buat session SNMP baru
$session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, $ip, $community);

$oid = 'ZXGPON-SERVICE-MIB::zxGponOntPhaseState'; 

$result = $session->walk($oid);

if ($result === false) {
    echo "Failed to get value from OID $oid";
} else {
    print_r($result);
}

// Tutup session SNMP
$session->close();
?>

//output

Warning: SNMP::walk(): Invalid object identifier: ZXGPON-SERVICE-MIB::zxGponOntPhaseState in C:\xampp\htdocs\snmpsuck\3.php on line 10
"Failed to get value from OID ZXGPON-SERVICE-MIB::zxGponOntPhaseState

I'm still confused whether what I'm doing is right or not, can anyone tell me what I should do?
I read in the forum I need a MIB file but I don't understand what the next step is.

Use this id instead
.1.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1012.3.28.2.1.4

Hi, it's better to explain how this can address the question. Be sure to read how to answer. Thank you
